# Visual Studio Team Services - edit link settings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I just noticed on  *Visual Studio Build* task the following:

[image]

To have parameters for common settings such as the solution file seems like a good idea to me, given that some parameters are used in more than 1 task... But I honestly don't like to use the wildcards, I'd rather use the path to the solution file.

If I click on **Link Settings** I am not able to edit the value for the **Solution** setting, is there a way to change it?

[image]

Answer (score 50, accepted):

When you link a setting from a build task it will not be editable in the Task itself. To edit it you need to go to the **Process** section of your build definition. There you can see a new parameter is added that maps to the solution setting in your MSBuild task.

[image: Build taks - Process]

You can see in the above image, the new parameter that was added to the process section of the build definition. You can clearly see if you unlink the setting from the build definition, the parameter will be removed. Here if you want, you can select the full path to the solution instead of using a wildcard

Comment: +1 If I could vote +1000 I would...this finally answered a null return set for google search on the topic...

Comment: An actual link where they show  This setting is linked to the 'Action' (Parameters.ActionIISWebsite) process parameter."  Would make sense.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming to this answer later, I'm using Azure DevOps Server 2019, and the names of things have changed.  I can get to the definition of "Solution" by going to Task -> Pipeline -> Parameters.
[image: slightly redacted screenshot of Azure Devops Server Build Pipeline page]